# Modifying numbered procedures in Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I created many numbered stored procedures in SQL Server 2008.

Their names are e.g.: `dbo.ProcName, dbo.ProcName;2, dbo.ProcName;3`,...

When I use rightclick on procedure name in procedures list in Management Studio 2008 and then click to `Modify` I can see and edit all stored procedure as I wrote above.

But in Management Studio 2012, after same action, I can see only the first procedure.

How to see and edit all stored procedures with the same name and suffix with semicolon?

Comment: Can view and edit only the first procedure.

Comment: Sounds like a bug - can you post a screenshot? What happens if you de-register then re-register your server? (View > Registered Servers)

Comment: FWIW, I suggest not using numbered procedures. As Martin pointed out, they're deprecated and actually not supported in a number of scenarios (e.g. Contained Databases).

Comment: OK Aaron, but if you have older database, then you need to sometimes edit any numbered procedure...

Comment: Yep, and Martin and I have both provided workarounds for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about [numbered stored procedures](http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/numbered-stored-procedures-will-be.html).

I can reproduce the same behaviour. After running the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[foo];1 @x int AS
  PRINT 'x is ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), @x)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[foo];2 @x char AS
  PRINT 'x is ' + @x
GO
```

Selecting "Foo" in object explorer then "Modify" shows both versions in SSMS 2008 but only the first one in SSMS 2012.

These have been [deprecated since 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) so I wouldn't be surprised if it is a deliberate decision not to support them in the tools any more. Looks like `Drop and Create` still lists both versions though.

Comment: +1 Nice catch, I totally missed that. I stopped reading that line at `dbo.ProcName,`

Comment: I never knew this feature existed. Incredible find.

Comment: Interesting that `Script As Create` and `Script As Drop and Create` work, but `Script As Alter` does not. Race you to Connect? :-)

Comment: Yes numbered procedures, I didn't know right title :-) Thanks, Martin. But how to easy view or edit numbered procedures in Management Studio 2012?

Comment: Like he said, you can choose Script Stored Procedure As > Drop and Create in order to view all versions in a single script.

Comment: There was an error Modify for numbered procedures before, but it was fixed in 2008: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/290112/impossible-to-manage-sps-that-have-multiple-versions#details

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Does seem inconsistent. Maybe I'm being too hasty saying it is a deliberate decision. Would be good to have this clarified.

Comment: So, ok, I will use Drop and Create. But there will be a looooong list of procedures in database than :-( Maybe Microsoft adds something like folders in future :-) Thanks, too both, guys!

Comment: Bugged: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764197/ssms-2012-inconsistently-handles-numbered-procedures

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'dbo.ProcName';
```

You'll have to inject the `GO`s yourself, though.

---

You can also get the metadata this way:

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ProcName')
UNION ALL
SELECT definition
FROM sys.numbered_procedures
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ProcName');
```

---

And this way:

```
SELECT [text] FROM syscomments
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ProcName');
```

---

And you can go through the Generate Scripts wizard:

1. right-click your database and choose Tasks > Generate Scripts
2. On the 'Choose Objects' screen, select 'Select specific database objects, check 'Stored Procedures', and expand to select the root name of the numbered stored procedure(s) you want to script.
3. On the 'Set Scripting Options' screen, choose 'Save to new query window.'
4. Click Next > Next > Finish.

---

I also filed a bug on this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764197/ssms-2012-inconsistently-handles-numbered-procedures